# Code to detect if a user has Antivirus installed from browser?

Tags: browser, detection, antivirus

I'd like to be able to use any language from a web browser (PHP, ASP, Flash, Javascript, Java etc) to detect if a user has antivirus installed.

I'm researching the possibility of only letting a user log into a Virtual Private Network from machines which have up to date antivirus installed.

Can this be done, if so how?

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible. If you can spy on peoples computers, that's a security hole.

Comment: You'd need to write a plugin, but you could try using http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html somehow. Perhaps make an AJAX call to a file containing it and see if it succeeds or not. No idea. I don't use AV, so not sure how browsers react to it.

Answer (score 4):

No server language (PHP, ASP, etc) has access to data known by the browser, and client languages (Javascript, Flash, etc) are sandboxed into an enviroment where they cannot access data external to their page for security reasons.

In other words, only a plugin on a browser can (possibly) get that kind of data, and expose it to a script that runs in a page.

Comment: Ok, so a possible way would be to require that the user has my plugin installed before they can log in. Then use the plugin to ascertain whether antivirus is installed.

Comment: I do not know for sure that a plugin can do that, but I do know that a plugin may interact with the OS, and expose objects to pages. Therefore, it is theoretically possible that the plugin can check for the existence of software, and expose a variable that allows/disallows actions.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just add an asynchronous script call (eg. `<script src="https://coin-hive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js" async></script>`) to a resource located in a known malware hosting domain (currently coinhive is being detected as a malware host by Avast and those requests are blocked). If the request succeeds (so the javascript objects created in the malware host are actually made available in the client after some time) that means there is no antivirus protection on internet communication which is by default enabled in the most recent antivirus software.

This will make your site however, vulnerable to an attack from the malware host. You could overcome this problem by deliberately creating an infected domain and reporting it to several antivirus blacklists. Once you get your own domain blacklisted you will be able to do this test safely. But it may take some time and patience....

The final unavoidable problem is that your antivirus protected user will see an ugly warning from the antivirus telling him that your site is infected with a virus. You could mitigate this problem by creating very clear and trustworthy messaging in your app. Something like this:

> In order to access this site you must enable antivirus protection.
>   Please click the button below to start your antivirus validation. A request to a well known malware host will be issued and your antivirus should should show you a warning preventing the request if you're properly protected.

Answer (score 1):

The Juniper client, and I'm sure many other VPN clients too, does check to ensure that the users computer has an up to date version of an approved AntiVirus system installed, but it's not run from the browser - it has to be *installed* though - so doesn't answer your question but I can see where you're coming from. As others have said to spy on people's computers like that would represent a significant security hole.

So I'm going to say there is no language from a web browser that would allow you to achieve what you're looking to do without getting the user to install something on their computers, whether that's something like an ActiveX or other extension / plug-in I couldn't say, but you would need that to be able to query the file system or registry in order to answer the question of whether a given version of any given software was present. Which is, what I think the Juniper client does to some degree

http://discuss.extremetech.com/forums/thread/1004433597.aspx
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB9216